# Delete every week all files except some folders (but not the files into these)

Tags: bash, cron, sh, except

I'm using this bash script to delete all files and folders located in a directory every week except three folders and the files contained into these.
But how can I now modify the script so that only these three foldres remain but not the files contained?
These 3 folders are necessary to a workflow but not the files contained (after 7 days).

```
find /Path/Folder/* -type d -mtime +7 ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE1"  ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE2"  ! -path "/Path/Folder/NODELETE3" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

What I want is

Before

```
Path/NODELETE1/files
Path/NODELETE2/files
Path/NODELETE3/files
Path/FOLDERS
Path/files
```

After

```
Path/NODELETE1
Path/NODELETE2
Path/NODELETE3
```

EDIT:

```
find /path/Folder/* -and -not -path "/path/Folder/DELEGATE*" -mtime +7 ! -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex ".*/path/Folder/(DOCUMENTS|WORK|PENDING)$" -delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first of all you don't need anymore the `-type d` if you want to delete files. you can use `regex` with `find` to deal with this case; a `regex` that matches everything that doesn't end with `NODELETE[1-3]`:

```
find path/folder/* -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex ".*path/folder/NODELETE[1-3]$"
```

this will match, for example:

```
$ find path/folder/* -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex ".*path/folder/NODELETE[1-3]$"
path/folder/asd
path/folder/asd/will_delete
path/folder/bleeegh
path/folder/NODELETE1/eraseme
path/folder/NODELETE2/a_folder
path/folder/NODELETE2/a_folder/delete_me
```

also, instead of `-exec rm -rf {}` you can use `-delete`:

```
$ find path/folder/* -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex ".*path/folder/NODELETE[1-3]$" -delete
$ tree
.
└── path
    └── folder
        ├── NODELETE1
        ├── NODELETE2
        └── NODELETE3

5 directories, 0 files
```

so, the folders remain, other folder and files are gone, and the files and folders inside `NODELETE[1-3]` are also gone.

don't forget to add `-mtime +7`! (i obviated it because it's not necessary to demonstrate the case)

---

if you want to keep other folders you can use an `OR` in the `regex` which won't delete the folders but will delete files inside them:

```
find path/folder/* -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex ".*path/folder/(NODELETE[1-3]|DOCUMENTS|WORK|DELEGATE)$" -delete
```

---

and if you want to keep the files of some folder you can specify another filter for `find`:

```
find [...] -and -not -path "path/folder/DOCUMENTS*"
```

notice that the `*` at the end will match not only the folder itself but all files inside it.

Comment: Whoa! Perfect explanation! And what about if I want to maintain other folders with different names, such as DOCUMENTS, WORK and DELEGATE (for a total of 6 folders).

Comment: And one last question: if I want to use your script BUT for one folder (for example DOCUMENTS, but it's an example) I want instead to maintain files (a combination of old script and yours) how can I do?

Comment: Thank you. May you give a look at the EDIT? Terminal gives me an error (find: warning: you have specified the -regextype option after a non-option argument -and, but options are not positional (-regextype affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments. - find: invalid expression; you have used a binary operator '-and' with nothing before it.)

Comment: Just remove the first `-and`, it's usage means in classical logic `(A ^ B)` where not only A but also B have to be true so the formula is true. This other formula `(^ A ^ B)` is not a valid expression in the language because the first `^` doesn't tie two propositions. That behavior is mimicked here: `find /path/Folder/* -and` is equivalent to starting the sentence with (^ A), so just remove it. This should leave you with: `find /path/Folder/* -not -path "/path/Folder/DELEGATE*" -mtime +7 ! -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex ".*/path/Folder/(DOCUMENTS|WORK|PENDING)$" -delete`

Comment: It now says the same thing but about "not" (find: warning: you have specified the -regextype option after a non-option argument -not, but options are not positional (-regextype affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.)

Comment: The script seems to work fine (tested w/0 mtime) but that warning appears.

Comment: Hmm, I see, does this throw a warning? `find /path/Folder/* -regextype posix-egrep -not -path "/path/Folder/DELEGATE*" -and -mtime +7 -and -not -regex ".*/path/Folder/(DOCUMENTS|WORK|PENDING)$" -delete`

Comment: Now it's working fine! No warning! Really thanks for your patience @odradek